# Passing apache2 digest authentication information to a wsgi script run by mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, authentication, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've got the directive

```
<VirtualHost *>
    <Location />
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "global"
        AuthDigestDomain /
        AuthUserFile /root/apache_users
        <Limit GET>
            Require valid-user
        </Limit>
    </Location>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /some/script.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess mywsgi user=someuser group=somegroup processes=2 threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup mywsgi
    ServerName some.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like to know in the /some/script.wsgi

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
    ])
    return ['Hello']
```

What user is logged in.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add `WSGIPassAuthorization On`:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    <Location />
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "global"
        AuthDigestDomain /
        AuthUserFile /root/apache_users
        <Limit GET>
            Require valid-user
        </Limit>
    </Location>
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /some/script.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess mywsgi user=someuser group=somegroup processes=2 threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup mywsgi
    ServerName some.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Then just read `environ['REMOTE_USER']`:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
    ])
    return ['Hello %s' % environ['REMOTE_USER']]
```

More information at [mod_wsgi documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#User_Authentication).

Comment: Much, much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

Additional information about Apache/mod_wsgi and access, authentication and authorization mechanisms can be found in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms

The information isn't passed by default because doing so could leak password information to applications which maybe shouldn't get it.