# Can I use HTTP Basic Authentication with Django?

Tags: django, http-authentication

We have a website running on Apache, access to which has a number of static pages protected via HTTP Basic authentication.

I've written a new part of the site with Django using Django's built in support for user management.

The problem I have is that users have to log in once via the HTTP Basic authentication and then again using a Django login form.  This both clumsy and very confusing for users.

I was wondering if anyone had found a way to make Django log a user in using the HTTP Basic authentication information.

I not expecting to pass a password to Django, but rather if a user `dave` has been authenticated by Apache then they should be automatically logged into Django as `dave` too.

(One option would be to make Apache and Django share a user store to ensure common usernames and passwords but this would still involve two login prompts which is what I'm trying to avoid.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This has been added to the Django 1.3 release.  See more current documentation for this here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/

Comment: Note, this doesn't work with the devserver or unittests, which makes it impossible to test and therefore almost useless. Don't use features that only work in production, and therefore can only be tested in production...

Answer (score 41):

For just supporting basic auth on some requests (and not mucking with the web server -- which is how someone might interpret your question title), you will want to look here:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/

Answer (score 10):

Do check out Oli's links. You basically see the authenticated username as verified by Basic HTTP Authentication in Django by looking at request.META['REMOTE_USER'].

**Update:** Tested the proposed patch for ticket [#689](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/689), which is available up-to-date in telenieko's git repository [here](http://www.marcfargas.com/gitweb/?p=django.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=trac/689-remote-user;hp=master). It applies cleanly at least on revision [9084](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk?rev=9084) of Django.

Activate the remote user authentication backend by

- adding the `RemoteUserAuthMiddleware` after `AuthenticationMiddleware`
- adding the setting `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserAuthBackend',)`

If you use lighttpd and FastCGI like I do, activate mod_auth, create credentials for a test user (I called it `testuser` and set `123` as the password) and configure the Django site to require basic authentication.

The following `urls.py` can be used to test the setup:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(regex='^$',
        view=lambda request: HttpResponse(repr(request), 'text/plain')),

    url(regex='^user/$',
        view=lambda request: HttpResponse(repr(request.user), 'text/plain')),

    url(regex='^users/$',
        view=lambda request: HttpResponse(
            ','.join(u.username for u in User.objects.all()),
            'text/plain')),
)
```

After reloading lighty and the Django FCGI server, loading the root of the site now asks for authentication and accepts the `testuser` credentials, and then outputs a dump of the request object. In request.META these new properties should be present:

```
'AUTH_TYPE': 'Basic'
'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6MTIz'
'REMOTE_USER': 'testuser'
```

The `/user/` URL can be used to check that you're indeed logged in as `testuser`:

```
<User: testuser>
```

And the `/users/` URL now lists the automatically added `testuser` (here the `admin` user I had created when doing `syncdb` is also shown):

```
admin,testuser
```

If you don't want to patch Django, it's trivial to detach the `RemoteUserAuthBackend` and `RemoteUserAuthMiddleware` classes into a separate module and refer to that in the Django settings.

Comment: Thanks for this.  In the end I did what you suggested and put the RemoteUserAuthBackend and RemoteUserAuthMiddleware classes in to my own module which I referenced in settings.py and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use basic autorization with django as something similar:

```
def post(self, request):
    auth_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '')
    token_type, _, credentials = auth_header.partition(' ')
    import base64
    expected = base64.b64encode(b'<username>:<password>').decode()
    if token_type != 'Basic' or credentials != expected:
        return HttpResponse(status=401)
    authorization success flow code ...
```

request.META contains key HTTP_AUTHORIZATION in which your Autorization is present.

In case if you are using apache with modWSGI, the key HTTP_AUTHORIZATION might not be present. You need to add below line in your WSGI config

**WSGIPassAuthorization On**

Refer this detailed answer:
[Passing apache2 digest authentication information to a wsgi script run by mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123499/passing-apache2-digest-authentication-information-to-a-wsgi-script-run-by-mod-ws)

Hope it is useful for someone who is wondering why HTTP_AUTHORIZATION key is not present

Answer (score 3):

There is [httpauth.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/689/httpauth.py). I'm still a complete newb with Django so I've no idea how it fits in exactly, but it should do what you're looking for.

Edit: here's [a longer bug thread on the subject](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/689).

Answer (score 0):

Because django can be run in several ways, and only modpython gives you close integration with Apache, I don't believe there is a way for django to log you in basic on Apache's basic auth. Authentication should really be done at the application level as it'll give you much more control and will be simpler. You really don't want the hassle of sharing a userdata between Python and Apache.

If you don't mind using a patched version of Django then there is a patch at http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/56/ which will give you some middleware to support basic auth.

Basic auth is really quite simple - if the user isn't logged in you return a 401 authentication required status code. This prompts the browser to display a login box. The browser will then supply the username and password as bas64 encoded strings. The wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication is pretty good.

If the patch doesn't do what you want then you could implement basic auth yourself quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a task for custom `AuthenticationBackend` - see [Django documentation on this subject](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources), djangosnippets.org has some real-life examples of such code (see [1](http://www.djangosnippets.org/tags/auth-backend/) or [2](http://www.djangosnippets.org/tags/authentication/)) (and this is not really a hard thing).

`AuthenticationBackend` subclasses have to have only 2 methods defined and their code is pretty straightforward: one has to return User object for user ID, the second has to perform credentials check and return User object if the credentials are valid.