# username:password in URL - how to handle this?

Tags: security, authentication, url, twitter

I found on [Assembla's webhook tool](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/help/webhook_tool_show) possibility to integrate with twitter. To do this assembla uses such url:

```
http://username:password@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

How twitter handles that kind of URL? Is this some standard? Does it require some special logic to perform login when someone POST data for URL with username:password? How can it be done in some web frameworks like RoR or Django?

Is this type of passing authentication data secure? (looks like not but maybe I'm missing something)

Comment: no point in even trying to master basic auth with twitter. it will be disabled 08.16.2010 http://www.countdowntooauth.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), supported by all the major browsers. It's also very insecure using HTTP. 
Here is a link to a Django implementation that adds Basic Auth to its security authentication chain.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152248/can-i-use-http-basic-authentication-with-django)

EDIT: Basic Auth is considered secure when using HTTPS but has other issues, it is the lowest common denominator when it comes to authentication but not ideal in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Should be parsed as a basic http authentication