# Does django natively integrate with HTTP Basic Authorization

Tags: python, django, http, authentication, basic-authentication

ONe of my system components is using the Basic HTTP Authrozation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication ) for log in information. Another part of my system is running a django application which uses the 'django.contrib.auth' app for authentication.

Would code like this work?

```
def urlHandler(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():    
     // ...
```

The urlHandler in this case would handle the request which has the `Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz` appended to its HTTP GET. Would the django authorization backend integrate with this?

Obviously I tried the above code and it does not seem to work...

Is there a middleware that would work in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152248/can-i-use-http-basic-authentication-with-django

Comment: @Reto: Ah! It did not show up in search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked and answered: [Can I use HTTP Basic Authentication with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152248/can-i-use-http-basic-authentication-with-django)

(The answer is yes. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/ for details.)