# Django Basic HTTP AUTH

Tags: python, django, authentication, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I am testing out Django 1.6 under Windows 7 using its integrated web server for debug purposes.

At some point I have a view that needs to be protected by authentication. (for debug purposes - not proper authentication).

The problem is that the browser won't ask me for authentication. This is my code:

```
if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
    print 'the header is there!!'
    auth = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split()
    ...
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser won't ask for authentication unless you have the necessary header on the *response*

See answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087736/202168