# Basic HTTP Auth with Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, authentication, http-headers, http-authentication

We are using the built in `django.contrib.auth` to handle most of our users log-ins/registrations.

However we also want to have basic HTTP Auth access to our app api so that we can access it via a command line interface project we are building.

The closest thing I found was this: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/

But that is from all way back in 2007 and there is nothing more recent, I was surprised to not see anything added to Django to resolve this issue. Is there a library that I may be missing?

My manager suggested I build some middleware to handle this, is this the best way?

Comment: There is a bunch of different options at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152248/can-i-use-http-basic-authentication-with-django :)

Comment: those are all very old.. is there any newer convention for doing this?